# Cannot retrieve List<String> from an SQLIte query method

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android project ,I have successfully created  an SQLite Database , Insertion operations are also successful.
I cannot retrieve the List into a method .

here is my calling  method:

```
protected void getTheServerList() {

        ServerManger info = new ServerManger(this);

        try {
            info.open();
            servers = info.getData();
            info.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EXCEPTION !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } finally {

        }
    }
```

and here is my SQLIte method

```
public List<String > getData() {

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_UNAME,
            KEY_PASSWORD };
    List<String> sItems=null;
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iUname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_UNAME);
    int iPass = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
    //sItems.add(KEY_NAME);
        result =c.getString(iName);

        sItems.add(result);


    }

    c.close();




    return sItems;
}
```

and I get an `Exception`

```
03-12 12:19:15.798: E/Database(390): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.proj/databases/PROJ_DB'
```

I can retrieve the String  , but not the-  List

Please help !

Comment: are you getting null pointer exception?

Answer (score 0):

initiate your list.. list is `null`

```
List<String> sItems=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: `new List<String>();` should probably be ArrayList or LinkedList like`new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: you can approve this answer if you get your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String > getData() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_UNAME,
            KEY_PASSWORD };
    List<String> sItems=new ArrayList<String>  // define instance Here you create listview but not creat this instance 
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iUname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_UNAME);
    int iPass = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
    //sItems.add(KEY_NAME);
        result =c.getString(iName);

        sItems.add(result);
    }
    c.close();
    return sItems;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to instantiate list every time. in a loop. so the list will have only one element. It should be before loop I guess